# Xcode unexpected error ( 0xC011) after running the program and when i am pressing on organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, csv

> xcode has encountered an expected error (0xC011)  ‘file
>   exists/SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-2083/DTDeviceKit/DTDKApplication.m:14‌​74

in the program i am writing some data to a different csv files for testing and  was working fine for 2 weeks  what do u think ? if the files saved on iPhone is the reason behind this error ? if so, what to do to solve this.
 if this is NOT what cause the error then ANY idea what is this error means?

Thanks in advance

Comment: to be precise, the error appears right after downloading the ios files to my desktop ? and the data is no more being written to the file.

Comment: Hey @Dina, did you ever find an answer for this? I am experiencing the same thing when attempting to download the container from the device.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, to fix I deleted the app off my device and re-executed in Xcode and I was able to view/download my container with no issues.